# Replacing div content on a site with new content with google extensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on this prank for my friends. I'm not an experienced programmer, and although i want to become one one day, I only have limited time to do this prank on my friends. So here's the deal. I use a webpage https://www.webpage.com/lol/data.asp (will be replaced with URL in code since this forum has limits on new users). On this site there is a div called "data_div" and I want to inject some code so when the page loads (when i load the extension ofc), the data in the div is replaced by the data in my HTML document. In this document i only have a table with new data that will replace the original table. How would i do this?

So far by reading forum posts (here and elswhere) and using google to help me, I've made little progress since i'm new to programming.

This is the code I got.

Manifest.json

```
{  "name": "prank",
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": [
    "URL"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["JQUERY URL", "URL"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.9.1.min.js", "myscript.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

myscript.js

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: "read_file"}, function(html){
    $("data_div").html(html);
});
```

background.html

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.cmd == "read_file") {
        $.ajax({
            url: chrome.extension.getURL("cont.html"),
            dataType: "html",
            success: sendResponse
        });
    }
})
```

and the HTML table content in cont.html.

This doesn't work, and if someone could make this work, or write me a thing that works I'd be most grateful.

The extension loads but doesnt do anything when i go on the site. I'm not even sure if I can access the div on the site and change it or if this is the right way to do it. I'm all ears guys, please, please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me as if your jquery selector is wrong in this line:

```
$("data_div").html(html);
```

You need to prepend the data_div with either a # or . depending on the mark up.

In your question you said that the div is called data_div, I am not sure what that means exactly. Below are the three options that I can think of, for what you might mean and the appropriate selector that you would need to use:
    data here       use this selector: $("#data_div")
    data here    use this selector: $(".data_div")
    data here     use this selector: $("div[name=data_div]")

If you need more information, you can read the docs about [JQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Selectors&redirect=no).

### Update

To make things more simple to debug, try changing the content of my script to (remove all the ajax calls):

$("#data_div").html('some test content');

If this works, you know that the problem is not with your selector, it is with the ajax. You can then build things up from there.

Comment: I tried changing to every three and it didnt work. It's probabbly the # since the div is defined like this `<div id="data_div">`. I also tried adding background into the manifest file like this: `"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },`

and that didnt work either. tried with persistent on T and F. i'm totaly lost :O